# List becoming nonetype in python

Tags: python, list, typeerror, nonetype, sage

```
x = (long list of data)
mymap = map(int, x.split())
box = []
mylist = list(mymap)
while len(mylist)>0:
    box.append([str(mylist[1])]*mylist[0])
    mylist = mylist[2:]
box.sort()
print(type(box))
type(box)
p=sns.displot(data = box)
p.set(xlabel = "Waiting time", ylabel = "Eruptions")
```

This is my code to create a histogram in sage from an extremely long list of data. The data is all like "3600 79 2800 58" etc with value and then frequency. Everything works well except the histogram generation itself. I've already tried outputting the list and it prints out perfectly fine.
This is the output when I run it:

```
<class 'list'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-87f016146a7f> in <module>
      9 print(type(box))
     10 type(box)
---> 11 p=sns.displot(data = box)
     12 p.set(xlabel = "Waiting time", ylabel = "Eruptions")
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/seaborn/distributions.py in displot(data, x, y, hue, row, col, weights, kind, rug, rug_kws, log_scale, legend, palette, hue_order, hue_norm, color, col_wrap, row_order, col_order, height, aspect, facet_kws, **kwargs)
   2225 
   2226             _assign_default_kwargs(hist_kws, p.plot_univariate_histogram, histplot)
-> 2227             p.plot_univariate_histogram(**hist_kws)
   2228 
   2229         else:
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/seaborn/distributions.py in plot_univariate_histogram(self, multiple, element, fill, common_norm, common_bins, shrink, kde, kde_kws, color, legend, line_kws, estimate_kws, **plot_kws)
    422 
    423         # First pass through the data to compute the histograms
--> 424         for sub_vars, sub_data in self.iter_data("hue", from_comp_data=True):
    425 
    426             # Prepare the relevant data
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/seaborn/_core.py in iter_data(self, grouping_vars, reverse, from_comp_data)
    994                 grouping_keys.append(self.var_levels.get(var, []))
    995 
--> 996             iter_keys = itertools.product(*grouping_keys)
    997             if reverse:
    998                 iter_keys = reversed(list(iter_keys))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Clearly box is a list since type(box) returns list, so what am I missing here? What is making its type become none?

Answer (score 0):

insted of using `while` use `for`, something like this

```
x = (long list of data)
mymap = map(int, x.split())
box = []
mylist = list(mymap)
for i in range (len(mylist)):
    box.insert(i, str(mylist[1] *mylist[0]) # or append
    mylist = mylist[2:]
box.sort()
print(type(box))
type(box)
p=sns.displot(data = box)
p.set(xlabel = "Waiting time", ylabel = "Eruptions")
```

Comment: now it gives me
mylist = mylist[2:]
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
which makes no sense